# How to use R's `browser()` function from command line when using `Rscript`

Tags: r, pdb

How do I run a script with `browser()` in it from the command line in such a way that it halt's execution?

```
Rscript file.R
```

Does not work for me. It seems I can only use `browser()` from `R`'s interpreter. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Generally in a circumstance like this, one would simply leave the original question, and open a new question that reflects your actual problem, since this is basically a wholly different problem, rather than a clarification of your original one.

Comment: In any case, I thought of calling this a [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1622797/324364) as well, but the answers there don't seem very satisfying, so perhaps you will attract a better one.

Comment: Cool -- I don't use SO much so thanks for the edit.

Comment: `browser` works in the interactive mode only.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

R functions such as `browser()`, `debugger()`, or `recover()` only work interactively.

If your script does not take command-line arguments a simple workaround is to start R and `source("myscript.R")`.

Comment: Added `browser()` to where the comment is in the `R` function, yet execution does not halt and all I get is this call trace `Called from: plusplus(1)`. Am I using it incorrectly? Could you edit that function I have in your answer and show me `browser()` is used please?

Comment: When you see `Called from: plusplus(1)`, the execution is stopped and you are in the debugger. Note that with byte-compiled R functions you might not be able to jump to the next step (it will jump to the end of the function). Did you check the help ('?browser' while in R) ?

Comment: Also look at the `trace` function which can be used to insert `browser` or `recover` or other things into the function that you want to debug.

Comment: Ok -- I see now that `browser()` works fine when using `R`'s interpreter. I have been trying to run this as a script from the command line with `Rscript file_name.R` and it would not halt execution. I will edit the question.